New Button on Related List with Parent Id on Lightning Component
I currently have a sObject that has it's New button overwritten by a Lightning Component. When creating a new record from a related list in the related list, is it possible to pass in the parent record Id? If I remember correctly, I'm able to get this in VF pages through the custom component and getting the retURL, but I'm not sure how to do that with the aura component (and the related list new button is kind of limited)

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but take a look at the navigation service: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation
This contains the state of the navigation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
